# can i handle UK errors in aspx?

Tags: c#, error-handling, custom-error-pages

> Server Error in '/' Application.  Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.Articles' with unique index 'UK_Articles'. The statement
>   has been terminated.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert
>   duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Articles' with unique index
>   'UK_Articles'. The statement has been terminated.

can i instead of internal server error 500 show UK error? can i catch the error and show it somehow?

EDIT:

```
 try
        {
            NHibernateSession.Save(entity);
        }

        catch (SqlException sex )
        {
            if (sex.Message.Contains("with unique index"))
                throw new UniqueConstraintException("UK ERROR");

            throw;
        }
```

but NHibernateSession.Save(entity) always trow GenericADOException and never SqlException. I want to catch insert at nhibernate so that i can ctach it globally.

Comment: `catch(SqlException) {...}` ? or just a custom error page?

Comment: You'd be better doing a check to see if there is a duplicate prior to your insert...

Comment: @Paddy, I think you can post this as the answer, actually.

Comment: @gaearon - it's not a whole solution, there's nothing to particularly stop someone from adding one in between your existence check and your insert, but it really depends on your system.

Comment: I'm just concerned that all answers here are focused on handling this specific error and ignore the real problem (row key is duplicate and OP needs to find out which column causes the issue and determine if a) index is needed at all, b) how to handle duplicates gracefully before error occurs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Sql Server.

You need a `try catch` block to handle [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
try
{
    // run inser or update query here
    myObj.InserRow();
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2601)
    {
        //"duplicate entry found!";
    }
    else
    {
        // some other kind of sql related exception
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // any other exception
}
```

Comment: i alwys get GenericADOException when inserting with nhibernate

Comment: @senzacionale, try getting inner exception of GenericADOException and check if its SqlException and compare exception number for desired results

Answer (score 1):

You can show manual errors using web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500Error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```